# Cannot increase "Levels Viewport" from 1 to 2 on "Subdivision Surface" Modifier

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I'm just started with Blender.  When I created the icing, I cannot increase the levels viewport subdivisions of the mesh.  If I increase the value from 1 to 2, the field turns orange and no increase in subdivisions occurs.

[Blender file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Ut8bQqx5TBVG2ds0lpx9WJE-y0iO7yK7/view?usp=sharing).

Before Increase: [image]

After Increase:
[image]

Comment: Can you add screenshots instead of just the blend file? It’s easier to answer it on my phone

Comment: It might have a keyframe, right click on it and delete all keyframes

Answer (score 3):

As Allen Simpson assumed - he is right - your subdivision is already keyframed. You can see this because the box color is filled green (it is keyframed, but not on this frame), orange (it was keyframed and was manually changed) or yellow (it has a keyframe on the current frame).

So right click on the value and choose "clear keyframes".

[image]

Then you can change the value.